# Using AngularJS in Windows store application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use AngularJS in my Windows store application.
I saw some suggested solutions:

http://prasadhonrao.com/windows-store-app-development-series-part-16-data-binding-using-angularjs/
http://rlbisbe.net/2013/11/20/angular-js-for-windows-store-apps-first-look/

But it doesn't seem to work.
I don't get the `Unable to add dynamic content` error, but Angular doesn't work.
Any other solutions (with some code samples)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for a Multi-device hybrid app:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/AngularJS-TODO-Sample-for-b651512a

You need to install VS2013 support for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps from here first:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx